# Regular Expression matching phone number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Need one regular expression in java script which matches the following

08 8223 7666
0800 118715
(07) 862 8715
+64 9 520 6369

Any help will be appreated
used

```
^([(+0-9]{1}[0-9 ]{11,13})?$
```

but this is not matching closing bracket

Comment: without context, you can use `^08 8223 7666 0800 118715 \(07\) 862 8715 \+64 9 520 6369$`. the important is what you do not want to match

Comment: `.*` will match them :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is intended to be a place where people help eachother solve problems, not where lazy people ask others to do their work for them. Please show us what you have tried and explain what difficulties you have run into.

Comment: @MartinJespersen Agreed. Why did this question get upvotes at all? This question clearly shows no (research) efforts, and is unclear.

Comment: I created an html file to test. My expression is new RegExp("^([(+0-9]{1} [0-9 ]{2} [^\)]{1} )?$"); Half done. But i am not geting

Answer (score 0):

If you try to match phone numbers, then search [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone%20number).

Answer (score 0):

following is a pattern `/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/`

for more info refer http://www.zparacha.com/phone_number_regex/

and http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/597