# regular expression to validate mobile number

Tags: javascript, regex

Please anyone help me to frame a regular expression to validate a mobile number in javascript. The criteria is i have to allow + symbol , - symbol , digits , space , open brace ( and close brace (
Eg: +0 (080) - 90343534554

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried this /^[0-9 ()-/+/(/)]+$/

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: You use backslash \ to escape and don't put the `-` (hyphen) in the middle. Put it at the end of the character class or at the beginning. And last, you don't need to escape metacharacters except backslash. Are all the phone numbers in that format?

Comment: this one could be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443911/regular-expression-matching-phone-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

If there is no restriction on the position or count of of special characters then you can use below regex:

```
^[+\-\d\s\(\)]+$
```

However according to standards, I would suggest to use :

```
^\+?[\d\s]+(\-([\d\s]|[\s]*(\([\d]+\)[\s]*))+)+$
```